# Webkit Bug? Broken CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, gecko

Working on part of my website. Here's my code: [`http://jsfiddle.net/firelizzard/ASdMq/`](http://jsfiddle.net/L59wY/10/)

In Chrome Beta (WebKit):

[image]

In Firefox (Gecko):

[image: Gecko Rendered]

Gecko is rendering this code how I want it. What is up with webkit?

Chrome User Agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (-OS-) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.11 Safari/535.19`

Firefox User Agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (-OS-) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1`

---

## Tally

Gecko:

- Works: Firefox 10

WebKit:

- Doesn't: Safari 5, Chrome 18

Trident:

- Works: Internet Explorer 8, 9
- Doesn't: Internet Explorer 7

Presto:

- Doesn't: Opera ?

Comment: This is how it looks in Opera: http://i.imgur.com/5gITr.png

Comment: <td class="dm_other horz">2</td><td class="dm_other horz">3</td> makes it look adequate in Opera 11.61..

Comment: @vines, would you post that as an answer so I can credit you? Using that, I fixed all of the problems (except in IE <8): `http://jsfiddle.net/firelizzard/ASdMq/3/`

Comment: Well, why not, whether it was helpful... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue definetely looked as a bug to me. While playing with the code posted on jsfiddle, I've noticed that adding some content to cells makes Opera 11.61 behave closer to what was expected:

```
<td class="dm_other horz">2</td>
<td class="dm_other horz">3</td>
```

I've came to try it because it reminded me of the [notorious whitespace problems](http://www.42inc.com/~estephen/htmlner/whitespacebugs.html) I'm hearing about from time to time :)