# More Webkit Fail

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303873/webkit-bug-broken-css).

My code is still here: [`http://jsfiddle.net/firelizzard/ASdMq/`](http://jsfiddle.net/L59wY/10/)

In Chrome Beta (WebKit):

[image: Webkit Rendered]

In Firefox (Gecko):

[image: Gecko Rendered]

Gecko is rendering this code how I want it. Again, what is up with webkit?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, my beef with webkit is the fact that the dark grey area is not centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that the HTML in your JSFiddle is far from optimal. You really should never ever use tables for layout. Not only do they require a bunch of unnecessary markup, they confuse screen readers and search engines and are more difficult to style than "normal" elements.

Here's a modern take on the design you're trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/UzPjW/

I've left comments in the CSS that should explain what's going on.

Comment: The reason I was using a table is because on my website, each corner and the rectangle on the top have images in them. I'll see if I can get yours to work with my images. The corner images are 12x12.

Comment: That's really not a reason to use a table. Just change the width/height to 12px (it won't match the inner border anymore though which is 10px) and give them background-images. Edit: example with images and 12x12: http://jsfiddle.net/UzPjW/1/